# Build share and alfresco war from source code for Alfresco 5.1

Tags: alfresco

I have downloaded the Alfresco source code for version 5.1 and imported in Eclipse. Now I have to do certain customization in dashboard, I have build `alfresco.war` by building `alfresco-platform` project in source code. How should I build `share.war` from the source code?

Comment: To customize the dashboard you don't have to build Alfresco. Create an AMP that includes your added feature. For example see https://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/alfresco-sdk-archetypes-repo-amp.html

Comment: i dont have to add feature. i need to override and change existing dashlets

Comment: In Alfresco 5.1, they split the Share code out into a second area of the source tree. Did you download the source code for Share too?

Comment: Thanks Gagravarr, my query is this only. I found out the share source code also

Answer (score 1):

The source code for Share can be found in this location: 
  https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/web-apps/Share/

You have to checkout the source of the tag you want, and then just run "mvn clean install" from there.
The share war will be in the `share/target` subfolder.

Note that this will also generate another `alfresco.war` in the `alfresco/target` subfolder. This one will have the `share-services.amp` pre-applied. This is probably the war you want to deploy: the one you got from the `alfresco-platform` project is missing the Share APIs, and will not be able to communicate with Share.